# jCarouselLite not working on this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

I am using jCarouselLite on this page

Here is the code

```
    //jcarousel 1.0.1
(function($){$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(o){o=$.extend({btnPrev:null,btnNext:null,btnGo:null,mouseWheel:false,auto:null,speed:200,easing:null,vertical:false,circular:true,visible:7,start:0,scroll:2,beforeStart:null,afterEnd:null},o||{});return this.each(function(){var b=false,animCss=o.vertical?"top":"left",sizeCss=o.vertical?"height":"width";var c=$(this),ul=$("ul",c),tLi=$("li",ul),tl=tLi.size(),v=o.visible;if(o.circular){ul.prepend(tLi.slice(tl-v-1+1).clone()).append(tLi.slice(0,v).clone());o.start+=v}var f=$("li",ul),itemLength=f.size(),curr=o.start;c.css("visibility","visible");f.css({overflow:"hidden",float:o.vertical?"none":"left"});ul.css({margin:"0",padding:"0",position:"relative","list-style-type":"none","z-index":"1"});c.css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative","z-index":"2",left:"0px"});var g=o.vertical?height(f):width(f);var h=g*itemLength;var j=g*v;f.css({width:f.width(),height:f.height()});ul.css(sizeCss,h+"px").css(animCss,-(curr*g));c.css(sizeCss,j+"px");if(o.btnPrev)$(o.btnPrev).click(function(){return go(curr-o.scroll)});if(o.btnNext)$(o.btnNext).click(function(){return go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.btnGo)$.each(o.btnGo,function(i,a){$(a).click(function(){return go(o.circular?o.visible+i:i)})});if(o.mouseWheel&&c.mousewheel)c.mousewheel(function(e,d){return d>0?go(curr-o.scroll):go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.auto)setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed);function vis(){return f.slice(curr).slice(0,v)};function go(a){if(!b){if(o.beforeStart)o.beforeStart.call(this,vis());if(o.circular){if(a<=o.start-v-1){ul.css(animCss,-((itemLength-(v*2))*g)+"px");curr=a==o.start-v-1?itemLength-(v*2)-1:itemLength-(v*2)-o.scroll}else if(a>=itemLength-v+1){ul.css(animCss,-((v)*g)+"px");curr=a==itemLength-v+1?v+1:v+o.scroll}else curr=a}else{if(a<0||a>itemLength-v)return;else curr=a}b=true;ul.animate(animCss=="left"?{left:-(curr*g)}:{top:-(curr*g)},o.speed,o.easing,function(){if(o.afterEnd)o.afterEnd.call(this,vis());b=false});if(!o.circular){$(o.btnPrev+","+o.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");$((curr-o.scroll<0&&o.btnPrev)||(curr+o.scroll>itemLength-v&&o.btnNext)||[]).addClass("disabled")}}return false}})};function css(a,b){return parseInt($.css(a[0],b))||0};function width(a){return a[0].offsetWidth+css(a,'marginLeft')+css(a,'marginRight')};function height(a){return a[0].offsetHeight+css(a,'marginTop')+css(a,'marginBottom')}})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: null,
                btnPrev: null,
                visible: 7,
                scroll: 2,
                vertical: false,
                circular: true,
                itemFallbackDimension: 150,
                start: 0,
                auto: 4000,
                speed: 1000
            });
});
```

On that way it's working some times with showing 7 images and sometimes it's showing only 5 images and sometimes no images and stopped working.

Please help me to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you post your html, please?
normally you can slide with the jcarousel just by preparing the html on the right way
like this:

```
<div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" id="pictureslide">
<div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" id="pic" style='position: relative;'>
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal">
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal' id='jcarousel-item-1'>
           <img src="pic/slide1.jpg" alt="slide" />
        </li>
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal' id="jcarousel-item-2" >
               <img src="pic/slide2.jpg" alt="slide" />
        </li>
        <li class='jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal' id="jcarousel-item-3" >
               <img src="pic/slide3.jpg" alt="slide" />
        </li>
    </ul> </div>                                

<div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal" style="display:'block'">
    <a class="controls prev" href="#"><img id="arrow-left" src="pic/arrow_left.png" alt="arrow-left" /></a>
</div>
<div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display:'block'">
    <a class="controls next" href="#"><img id="arrow-right" src="pic/arrow_right.png" alt="arrow-right"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END #pictureslide -->
```

in Javascript you only have to write this (the id is at the ul):

```
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
       "wrap": 'circular',
       "scroll": 2
         ....
    });
```

Comment: If you refresh the page few times you can see

Comment: I have removed that code and used marquee as a alternative way.